# I'm using Magick.NET in my apps, should I append license to my app directly or can I link it through my website?

Tags: licensing, apache-2.0

I have two questions about Magick.NET license:

1. As the title says, I'm making apps that use the Magick.NET library. Since Magick.NET is under the Apache 2 license, I wonder if I have to append Apache 2 license to my apps directly or can I have it on my website and link to it in my app?
2. Since Magick.NET originates from ImageMagick, Should I add ImageMagick license to my apps? I don't use ImageMagick, just only Magick.NET.

Edit: My apps are commercial.

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate the [Apache License](https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0) is quite wordy, but Section 4(a) is honestly very clear:

> You must give any other recipients of the Work or Derivative Works a copy of this License

That means "give them a copy of the license", not "link to the license".

With regards to ImageMagick, if you are distributing ImageMagick itself, you must comply with its license.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I use only Magick.NET not ImageMagick in my apps. I'm clear that I have to append it to my apps now.